# How do I position the labelText field above the labelInputBorder as seen in provided screenshot

Tags: flutter-web

Problem

I am tasked with implementing an input text field where the labelText sits above the input box.

[image: Design Mockup]

I have been unsuccessful in locating any resources that help me implement this.

Here is what I have so far...

[image]

```
    class UploadFormTextField extends TextFormField {
  UploadFormTextField({labelText, initialValue, onSaved, validator, maxLength})
      : super(
          initialValue: initialValue,
          autofocus: true,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              errorMaxLines: 3,
              labelText: labelText,
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              filled: false,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22.0,
                color: kPrimaryBlack,
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              errorStyle: kFormErrorStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid))),
          onSaved: onSaved,
          validator: validator,
          maxLength: maxLength,
        );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal - added my current code to the original question